# Reorder Checkout Elements in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

through to legal issues in Germany, we have to change the order of the Checkout-Review on the right.
We need the following order:

- Your Order
- Payment Methods
- Accept Terms and Conditions
- Product Table
- Order Button

Payment Methods
Accept Terms and Conditions
Product Table
Order Button

I've attached a Screenshot
(Link: https://goo.gl/pmzmGP )
of how it should look like.
Is this possible and if yes: how?